# Fire damage required for nuclear fusion

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I was reading the entry for the [Necklace of Fireballs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necklace-of-fireballs/) and noticed the clause about magical fire detonating the entire necklace. This got me thinking. If one had a bottle of hydrogen and placed in it in a barrel with an absurd number (Could be thousands...) of Necklaces of Fireballs and detonated the the necklaces, would the hydrogen fuse...

With this sort of setup, one can stack a really absurd amount of fire damage into a 20ft radius for a single round. This brings me to the question: How much fire damage would be required to ignite nuclear fusion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No amount of fire damage is enough to initiate nuclear fusion. This is for two unrelated reasons:

1. D&D isn't a physics simulator, and has no concept of this “nuclear fusion” you speak of.
2. Even in a game of D&D where the DM was happy to houserule nuclear energy physics into the game, nuclear fusion needs *pressure* to begin. The *necklace* works as the *fireball* spell, which does fire damage but no force damage, and therefore has no explosive pressure. Since that pressure is missing, nuclear fusion is just not in the cards.

   (Note that mere fission is not in the cards either. A fission bomb works by smashing the sub-critical fissionable material together using the contained pressure of conventional explosives, so it also needs pressure that *fireball* can't provide. Notably, no amount of conventional explosives in the real world are used to initiate *fusion* — how our fusion bombs work instead is adding fusible material to a fission bomb; the conventional explosives initiate fission, and the resulting *atomic bomb* is needed to even have a chance at initiating the fusion of the fusible materials. It's really hard to make a fusion bomb work!)

So for two separate reasons, a lot of *necklaces of fireballs* just isn't going to get you to fission, let alone fusion.

That said, it's fantasy — if your DM and fellow players are game and want to toy with atomic and hydrogen bombs, who's going to stop you or tell you your physics is wrong? In that case, have fun! :) And [don't accidentally give yourself fatal radiation poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core).

Comment: Great point about pressure. I see one would also need to uniformly apply some amount of force damage to the hydrogen bottle along with the heat from the necklace of fireballs. That might generate the required pressure...

Comment: @Andrew Yeah. [Fission is much easier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon#Fission_weapons) and can be achieved just by pushing two chunks of subcritical nuclear fuel together, but if that's lying around in a D&D game then you don't need the *necklace* at all. (*Mage hand* or something might do though.) Fusion is by comparison super tricky.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is setup would be purely in the realm of a thought experiment, as the GP cost of these items would be very high. But the necklaces of fireball example does provide a way for nearly unlimited heat and fire damage in a 20 ft radius. It is also why, as a GM, I believe the item is kind of broken.

Comment: The physics part isn't that simple.  Temperature and pressure are related, so by heating a thing you will also cause it to expand and/or increase the pressure on it, usually.  With an arbitrarily large amount of free energy in the form of heat, spontaneous fission ought to be possible, as well as particle creation, and then (in the subsequent cooling process) fusion.  Basically, you could, with arbitrarily large and instantaneously present heating, cause a mini big-bang.  Still +1 because you shouldn't assume any of this is true in an arbitrary setting, and especially not in D&D.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Yep, except that “D&D physics” of a *fireball* has force damage of zero that doesn't scale with the fire damage (∞ *fireball* fire damage still comes with 0 force damage), so I'm considering magic fireballs to have somehow decoupled that here. (Basically: unrigorous, abstract magic systems don't mix well with particle physics!)

Answer (score 2):

### Physics time!

Let's start simple:

- Fusion can happen in several combinations. For in the reaction <sup>2</sup>H+<sup>3</sup>H to <sup>4</sup>He+n. That's the classic Deuterium-Tritium one.
- To get fusion actually going, you need to overcome the Coulomb-barrier between the cores of particles. For the aforementioned Deuterium-Tritium-Fusion (D-T-Fusion), this barrier of 0.1 MeV would be overcome by 2 particles just hanging around next to each other at 1.2 *billion* kelvin - or impacting into each other at more than 0.1 MeV of kinetic energy in standard air pressure

  - This temperature (or rather average kinetic energy needed) is lowered somewhat by tunneling effect and the fact that temperature is (in thermodynamics) the average kinetic energy of a particle, and thus a gas at 1.2 billion kelvin does have particles that have a kinetic energy well beyond what is needed and well less than what is needed to break the culomb barrier. So a safe assumption that some fusion could happen at room pressure would be 1 billion kelvin.
- Pressure in itself does not change the temperature needed in a huge degree, however it increases the nuber of particles and temperature (PV=nRT for you nerds), and thus the chance of two particles of sufficient kinetic energy getting close enough (10<sup>-15</sup> m, which is pretty much cores touching) effectively giving us a *little* extra drop in temperature needed: We'd only need 100 million kelvin at sun core pressure of 250 times average atmospheric pressure.

  - But the sun only has 15.6 million Kelvin core temperature! why does it work?! Oh, it has no *gas* but a *plasma* to begin with, which drops the culomb barrier slightly more. In these temperature-pressure-surroundings we have only relativistic particles, that means particles that move more than 0.1 times the speed of light. Under these conditions, if two particles smash into each other frontal they have 1-2 magnitudes more kinetic energy than when one moving one hits a standing one, as their moved mass increases with speed, increasing their kinetic energy... E<sub>kin</sub>=m<sub>0</sub>c²

Sidenote: We can't achieve such kinetic energy with conventional explosions. We use lasers, neutron beams and keep the ionized gas confined and compressed in a vacuum by magnetic fields, just to keep the temperature & pressure in the area we need to fuse a few grams in [laboratory environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak). Currently they manage 10-100 keV environment by gobbling up something in the area of [50 GW.](https://www.euro-fusion.org/faq/how-much-more-energy-will-it-take-a-tokamak-over-the-breakeven-point-to-actually-produce-power-due-to-loss-of-energy-in-the-processes-of-electricity-production/)

### Ok, enough physics lecture!

What does that mean for a barrel of hydrogen and fireball chains?!

First of all, the barrel needs to be sunken to about 2500 meters depth with one side open to get the needed pressure on the gas inside. Then the necklaces have to heat it up to 15 million kelvin without boiling away the ocean around it. There is a little problem though: water boils at 372.15 kelvin and can soak up to 2108 kJ of energy per kilo and only then go up by one kelvin of temperature. Which is a lot. Assuming the water was 277.15 (most dense water) before, that is 96 Kelvin increase, so 202,368 kJ of energy per kilogram *lost* into the surrounding water, only to make the water boil as it touches the barrel.

So, how much energy does such a necklace contain at all? It makes a 20 feet diameter fireball at 1 atmosphere. Assuming a fireball is somewhat aequivalent to a cloud of burning fuel (or film explosion), it would be a 6 meter diameter sphere. Of these, only a very minor ammount has to be actual fuel. After some research, it seems that 2 to 4 bags of gasoline (sadly nobody said how much is in one) would be sufficient. [This](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/5.9781600865497.0048.0060) paper speaks abotu the aerosol particle size, reducing the fuel (and thus contained energy) needed by using smaller particles, but that is not leading to the goal. After all, the whole point is: it just doesn't get hot enough.

### tl;dr:

The power confined in each chain of fire is swallowed by the water that is needed to put up the needed pressure on the gas in the barrel, and if this first thin layer of water is vaporized and starts to rise, new water flows in from the surrounding ocean, keeping the temperature at a nice, cool 277.15 Kelvin until we either run out of necklaces or the whole ocean is boiled away and we lack the pressure needed to achieve fusion.

---

### BUT...

> "What if I use a huge blob of hydrogen and rely on gravitational pull and then bomb that thing with fireballs?!"

Ok THAT is actually a feasable experiment. Let's take a huge blob of hydrogen. Like... [a cloud several lightyears in diameter at above 1 particle per cubic meter](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_1647.html). That experiment doesn't need any fireballs, as its graitational pull and contraction in the end will lead to a self igniting fireball called star. It just takes a few million years.